# How to open a Aptana/SVN project in "Sublime 2 Text"

Tags: aptana3, sublimetext2

i want to change my IDE from Aptana Studio 3 to Sublime 2 Text.

But i have the Problem that i dont know how to open my old SVN projects
with Sublime 2.

In Sublime 2 i installed this "http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/svn" but 
i cannot "Checkout" a Project.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Project => Add Folder To Project (find your folder) => save project as (save back to your folder)

Comment: so simple ?? and it will recognize the svn ??

Comment: If you install an svn plugin it will (just tried it with the one called "SVN") ;)